# What's the limit of $\sqrt[n]{x_n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I was wondering about this problem, and haven't been able to solve it at all. Let $(x_n)$ be a real non-negative sequence, such that $x_{n+m}\le x_mx_n$, for every $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. I'm asked to prove $\sqrt[n]{x_n}$ converges.

I use $y_n=\frac{x_n}{x_1^n}$, and it has a limit $a$ because of monotony. If $a\ne 0$, I got to prove $\sqrt[n]{y_n}\rightarrow 1$, so $\sqrt[n]{x_n}\rightarrow x_1$, but I don't know what to do if $a=0$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take logarithm. The question reduces to something standard.

Comment: Prove that the limit is $\inf \{\sqrt[n]{x_n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}_+\}$.